# If I keep flipping a coin till I get heads, what is the probability I will do more than 3 flips?

Tags: probability

The probability of getting heads is p > 0. Now, I will keep flipping the coin, till I get heads. What is the probability, I did more than three flips?

According to the textbook, the probability is $(1-p)^3$ but I have no idea how to get this result.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You do more than three flips if and only if the first three flips are all tails.  That occurs when the first flip is tails (*which occurs with probability $(1-p)$*), the second flip is also tails (*which also occurs with probability $(1-p)$*), and similarly for the third flip.  The probability of all of these occurring is the product of the probabilities and is as such $(1-p)\times (1-p)\times (1-p)=(1-p)^3$

Comment: OK, I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The coin can only land on heads or tails. Therefore, if the chance of tails is heads is $p$, then the chances of tails must be $1-p$ in order for the two probabilities to sum to $1$.

As User JMoravitz has already pointed out, the only way in which you can see more than $3$ flips (i.e. $4$ or more flips) is if the first three tosses come out as tails. Therefore, the probability is

$$
(1-p) \times (1-p) \times (1-p) = (1-p)^3
$$

NB  we can only multiply the probabilities together in this way if the events are *independent* from each other. In this case, they are, as one coin flip does not affect any other.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.